# ASP.NET Core SignalR - browser window remains "loading" for 120 seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

### Background

I'm trying to build an ASP.NET Core web application that requires bidirectional real-time communication between the server and client. I've tried using the [ASP.NET Core port of SignalR](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server) for this.

### Environment

- Windows 7 64-bit development machine
- Visual Studio 2015 IDE
- Firefox 49.0.1 (browser used for testing)
- `Microsoft.NETCore.App` version 1.0.1
- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server` version 0.1.0-rtm-21431 (server-side SignalR)
- `jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js` (client-side SignalR)
- Nuget sources:

  - Nuget (https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json")
  - Code Comb (https://www.myget.org/F/codecomb-rc2/api/v3/index.json)
  - Internal company Nuget repository

### Problem

When I launch the application (`IIS Express` button in VS2015), a new Firefox tab opens at `localhost:...`, rendering my `Views\Home\Index.cshtml`. This works fine and the page seems to be fully loaded within a few seconds, but the "loading" spinning wheel icon persists for about 123 seconds.

From Application Insights, I can see that the browser makes a GET request for "Home/Index" and "/signalr/hubs" immediately, followed by a 120 second pause before further signalr requests are made:

[image: Comms test application insights]

At about the same time as these last three events, I see the following logs appear in Firefox's debugger:

```
[11:37:43 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'communicationshub'.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js:82:17
[11:37:43 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22communicationshub%22%7D%5D'.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js:82:17
[11:37:43 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: longPolling transport starting.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js:82:17
[11:37:43 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Opening long polling request to 'http://localhost:61192/signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=CfDJ8POyhc9yf1ZCtsJ9aOnflZgBHgcMoU0sLdQxkrNhkMLtIP%2BGWCL%2BPNY5H1RhK%2Fl92vibhhTu1PQxPpkcg%2BhpFwYw%2BNyFcTNplZ2HPBXd4QVZVOlP7QR9eIkuoCIDZMFedKEk7kzC7cXBhoF8838KJEAZnGz%2BqQGlePSxmoM6WVhW&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22communicationshub%22%7D%5D'.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js:82:17
[11:37:43 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Long poll complete.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js:82:17
[11:37:43 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: LongPolling connected.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js:82:17
[11:37:43 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: longPolling transport connected. Initiating start request.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js:82:17
[11:37:43 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Opening long polling request to 'http://localhost:61192/signalr/poll?transport=longPolling&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=CfDJ8POyhc9yf1ZCtsJ9aOnflZgBHgcMoU0sLdQxkrNhkMLtIP%2BGWCL%2BPNY5H1RhK%2Fl92vibhhTu1PQxPpkcg%2BhpFwYw%2BNyFcTNplZ2HPBXd4QVZVOlP7QR9eIkuoCIDZMFedKEk7kzC7cXBhoF8838KJEAZnGz%2BqQGlePSxmoM6WVhW&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22communicationshub%22%7D%5D'.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js:82:17
[11:37:43 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js:82:17
Connected. connectionId : 9d6591af-f1b1-403f-bc42-c81a1b33b25clocalhost:61192:79:21
[11:39:34 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Long poll complete.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js:82:17
[11:39:34 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Opening long polling request to 'http://localhost:61192/signalr/poll?transport=longPolling&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=CfDJ8POyhc9yf1ZCtsJ9aOnflZgBHgcMoU0sLdQxkrNhkMLtIP%2BGWCL%2BPNY5H1RhK%2Fl92vibhhTu1PQxPpkcg%2BhpFwYw%2BNyFcTNplZ2HPBXd4QVZVOlP7QR9eIkuoCIDZMFedKEk7kzC7cXBhoF8838KJEAZnGz%2BqQGlePSxmoM6WVhW&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22communicationshub%22%7D%5D'.
```

My questions are:

- Why is it taking so long to establish a connection?
- How can I eliminate this delay so that all this happens immediately, instead of after 123 seconds?

### Further Details

Startup - ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddSignalR(options =>
    {
        options.Hubs.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    });

    services.AddSingleton<CommunicationsHub>();
    services.AddScoped<ICommunicationsManager, CommunicationsManager>();
}
```

Startup - Configure:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseWebSockets();
    app.UseSignalR();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

CommunicationsHub:

```
public class CommunicationsHub : Hub
{
    public class TransmissionRequestedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public TransmissionRequestedEventArgs(GenericMessage message)
        {
            this.Message = message;
        }

        public GenericMessage Message { get; }
    }

    private readonly IHubContext context;

    public CommunicationsHub(IConnectionManager connectionManager)
    {
        this.context = connectionManager.GetHubContext<CommunicationsHub>();
    }

    public event EventHandler<TransmissionRequestedEventArgs> MessageTransmissionRequested;

    public void OnMessageReceived(GenericMessage message)
    {
        context.Clients.All.onMessageReceived(message);
    }

    public void SendMessage(GenericMessage message)
    {
        MessageTransmissionRequested?.Invoke(this, new TransmissionRequestedEventArgs(message));
        context.Clients.All.onMessageSent(message);
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@using <<Company>>.Communications.Core
@model IEnumerable<ICommunicationService>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

@section scripts
{
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var $tbl = $("#data");
            var comms = $.connection.communicationsHub;
            comms.client.onMessageReceived = function (message) {
                console.log("Message received: " + message)
            };
            comms.client.onMessageSent = function (message) {
                console.log("Message sent: " + message)
            };

            $.connection.hub.logging = true;
            console.log($.connection.hub.logging);
            $.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling' })
                .done(function () {
                    console.log('Connected. connectionId : ' + $.connection.hub.id);
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    console.log('Could not connect!');
                });
        });
    </script>
}

Please select a communications service to test:
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    @foreach (var controller in Model)
    {
        <li role="presentation">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>@controller
        </li>
    }
</ul>

<table id="data"></table>
```

**Update 1**

It turns out this has nothing to do with SignalR - my fault.

Oddly, I found that my "Index" view still took a very long time to load even after moving all the SignalR logic to another view. I went backwards through my VCS history until I found the commit where the problem was introduced and tracked down the root of the problem. My `HomeController` class is injected with an instance of `ICommunicationManager` during construction, which will cause my `CommunicationManager` to be instantiated. This is the constructor for `CommunicationManager`:

```
public CommunicationsManager()
{
    var assemblies = from name in DependencyContext.Default.GetDefaultAssemblyNames()
                     where name.Name.StartsWith("<<Company Name>>")
                     select Assembly.Load(name);

    var configuration = new ContainerConfiguration()
        .WithAssemblies(assemblies);

    var container = configuration.CreateContainer();
    this.Candidates = container.GetExports<ICommunicationService>();
}
```

If I get rid of this logic and set `this.Candidates` to an empty list, the page loads fine without the 120+ second spinning wheel. Weirdly, the code itself executes pretty quickly and the page loads with all the expected exports.

I'll try to figure out why this is happening and after that I'll close the question. Any help would still be appreciated.

**Update 2**

I've got a much better understanding of the root of the problem now. `ICommunicationManager` (indirectly) inherits `IDisposable`. I implement the disposal pattern in `CommunicationManager`:

```
#region IDisposable Support
private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!disposedValue)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            this.Candidates.ToList().ForEach(it => it.Dispose());
        }
        disposedValue = true;
    }
}

// This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
public void Dispose()
{
    // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
    Dispose(true);
}
#endregion
```

By breakpointing this code, I've found that something (the ASP.NET framework I assume) is trying to dispose the communication manager shortly after returning the "Index" view *even though* `HomeController` maintains a reference to it as one of its private fields. By adding a `return` statement right at the start of `Dispose` (to prevent actually disposing anything), I find that the loading issue disappears.

How can I prevent the ASP.NET framework (or whatever it is) from automatically disposing `CommunicationManager`? I'd like to only dispose it when the web service is shutdown.

**Update 3**

I've decided I didn't actually need `ICommunicationManager` to implement `ICommunicationService`, in which case I can dump disposal support. That means my application is now working properly. However, I'd still appreciate any information about why `ICommunicationManager.Dispose()` was automatically being closed - I couldn't find anything myself from a cursory search.

Comment: It shouldn't take that long (though I am not sure where you got your SignalR server from...). Try creating a very basic SiganlR app and see if it reproduces. Also, you don't need the ctor on your hub class. `Clients` should be available without this https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/blob/623bd9fdf339da2990e6c75f3dbc6a9e2fa2499f/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server/Hub.cs#L23

Comment: I tracked down the problem - I've updated my post. "Also, you don't need the ctor on your hub class. Clients should be available without this" You're right, but I swear I tried this originally and got an exception along the lines of "hub context outside request thread" or something. I've changed it as you suggested and it seems to work as well as before, though.

Comment: I think this is because you used AddScoped to register ICommunicationManager and _Scoped lifetime services are created once per request._ so they were disposed at the end of the scope.

Comment: @Pawel That's probably it. I'll check this tomorrow and if you're right, you can submit it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Pawel By temporarily re-implementing IDisposable, I can confirm you're right - `AddSingleton` resolves the issue. If you want, you can submit an answer along the lines of "This has nothing to do with SignalR and is instead caused by premature disposal of CommunicationManager...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CommunicationsManager` is being disposed because you registered it with `AddScoped`. *Scoped lifetime services are created once per request* and they are disposed at the end of the scope (i.e. request).